# ASP.NET: Generating Order ID?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, random

I am getting ready to launch a website I designed in ASP.NET.

The problem is, I don't want my customers to have a super low order id(example:#00000001).

How would I generate a Unique(and random) Order ID, so the customer would get an order number like K20434034?

Comment: Yes sir.I am using SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Identity Seed for your OrderId to a large number.  Then when you present an order number to the user, you could have a constant that you prepend to the order id (like all orders start with K), or you could generate a random character string and store that on the order record as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options from both the business tier and database:

### Consider

- a random number has a chance of collision
- it is probably best not to expose an internal ID, especially a sequential one
- a long value will annoy users if they ever have to type or speak it

### Options

- Generate a cryptographically random number (an `Int64` generated with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` has a very low chance of collision or predictability)
- begin an auto-incremented column which begins at some arbitrary number other than zero
- use `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (or `System.Guid`) and base 62 encode the bytes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just start the identity seed at some higher number if all you care about is that they don't think the number is low. The problem with random is that there is always the chance for collisions, and it gets more and more expensive to check for duplicates as the number of existing order IDs piles up.

Answer (score -1):

Make column data type as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER . This data type will provide you the ID in the below mentioned format. Hope this fulfills the need.

B85E62C3-DC56-40C0-852A-49F759AC68FB.